# Обработка целой и дробной части вещественного числа в С++

Tags: c++, double, float

Всем привет.

Вопрос в том, какой способ предпочтительнее для подсчета количества цифр в дробной и целой частях вещественного числа. В основном предлагаются варианты перевода в строку или цикл деления с остатком. Есть ли еще какие-нибудь способы?

Вопрос сюда же: как правильно перевести вещественное число в строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого разумного способа не существует. Числа типа `double`/`float` хранятся в виде двоичной дроби. Поскольку число `0.3` не представимо точно в виде конечной двоичной дроби, после присвоения

```
double d = 0.3;
```

вы не сможете выяснить, что в исходном числе один десятичный разряд.

Дополнительное чтение: [OMG Ponies!!!](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/)